# Correlating dymanic value Gatling

Tags: regex, gatling

I make a call that responds with a 304 and a link like this:

```
    <p>This document you requested has moved 
    temporarily.</p>
    <p>It's now at <a href="https://zzz.journal.html#YjExMDBmMWYtZTExZC00NzJlLTk4OWQtM2YzMDFhMTkwYmM5/oversikt">https://xxx.journal-test.no/hpp-webapp/zzzjournal.html#YjExMDBmMWYtZTExZC00NzJlLTk4OWQtM2YzMDFhMTkwYmM5/oversikt</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

I want to capture and save the value `YjExMDBmMWYtZTExZC00NzJlLTk4OWQtM2YzMDFhMTkwYmM5`
I assume right and left and the boundary is `html#` and `/oversikt`

How can I write a check to obtain the value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex:
`.check(regex("html#(.*?)\/oversikt").saveAs("token"))`